# Query shows values from tables differently

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select, sum

I have 3 tables (attendance, allowances and deductions) with some records in  attendance.Wage, allowances.Amount, deductions.Amount columns. And I want to "SUM" values in these columns with selected date.

Summed up values must be

- attendance.Wage:**100**
- allowances.Amount:**150**
- deductions.Amount:**120**

but with my query values are seeing very different.

```
SELECT Name, SUM(attendance.Wage), SUM(allowances.Amount), SUM(deductions.Amount) FROM employees
INNER JOIN attendance USING (EmployeeID)
INNER JOIN allowances USING (EmployeeID)
INNER JOIN deductions USING (EmployeeID)
WHERE MONTH(attendance.Date) = 6 AND YEAR(attendance.Date) = 2020 
AND
MONTH(allowances.Date) = 6 AND YEAR(allowances.Date) = 2020 
AND
MONTH(deductions.Date) = 6 AND YEAR(deductions.Date) = 2020 
GROUP BY employees.EmployeeID;
```

Output of the query:

- attendance.Wage:**400**
- allowances.Amount:**900**
- deductions.Amount:**720**

Why the values are multiplying or increasing? How can I fix that?

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are getting multiple rows from each table and the `join` is multiplying them.

Without additional information, I would recommend correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT e.Name,
       (SELECT SUM(a.Wage)
        FROM attendance a
        WHERE a.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID AND
              a.date >= '2020-06-01' AND a.date < '2020-07-01'
       ),
       (SELECT SUM(a.Amount)
        FROM allowances a
        WHERE a.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID AND
              a.date >= '2020-06-01' AND a.date < '2020-07-01'
       ),
       (SELECT SUM(d.Amount)
        FROM deduction d
        WHERE d.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID AND
              d.date >= '2020-06-01' AND d.date < '2020-07-01'
       )
FROM employees e;
```

With an index on `(EmployeeId, date, amount/wage)` in each of the three tables, this should also have better performance than alternatives using explicit aggregations and joins.

Comment: Thanks. Now I realized. But I can't understand why this have better performance than alternatives using explicit aggregations and joins? (I wan't to learn this too)

Comment: @user13758994 . . . Replacing the outer aggregation with look ups in an index is why the performance is probably going to be better.  The only exception would be if you had a really large `employees` table and most of them had no records in any of the tables in those months.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to push the aggregation down in subqueries, otherwise the sums count each value multiple times.

```
SELECT e.Name, ad.total_attendance, aw.total_allowances, dd.total_deductions
FROM employees e
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT EmployeeID, SUM(wage) total_attendance
    FROM attendance 
    WHERE date >= '2020-06-01' and date < '2020-07-01'
    GROUP BY EmployeeID
) ad USING (EmployeeID)
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT EmployeeID, SUM(amount) total_allowances
    FROM allowances 
    WHERE date >= '2020-06-01' and date < '2020-07-01'
    GROUP BY EmployeeID
) aw USING (EmployeeID)
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT EmployeeID, SUM(amount) total_deductions
    FROM deductions 
    WHERE date >= '2020-06-01' and date < '2020-07-01'
    GROUP BY EmployeeID
) dd USING (EmployeeID)
```

Comment: Thank. It's work too. But in "e.Name" e is not defined but its just a little miss. All others work.

Comment: @user13758994: fixed.